# Can I use angular2 server for running web pages?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

> Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http,
>   data, chrome, chrome-extension

I have some folders outside of the src folder in angular2.
can I use the localhost in angular2 (ng-serve)
to load those pages using jQuery?

I tried to get them through
`localhost:4200/C/users/test/index.html` <-- not seems to work.

hope you can help.
thanks

Comment: A localhost is a server, Angular is not a server, and jQuery has nothing to do with any of these :) I'm struggling to understand your question

Comment: "ng serve builds the application and starts a web server" i have some static html file outside of the src folder i want to inject the html file to another html file, i want to use localhost angular offer to load the html page before inject it     $.get( "C:/Users/test/Documents/client/test-ads/ads.html", function( data ) {

});

Comment: yes, `ng serve` starts a ready-made local server (using NodeJS behind the scenes). You can't customize it, and you can't change its code. It just serves your Angular app, that's it. If you want a real, complete, custom local server, you'll have to write it yourself (with NodeJS or another server-side technology). This custom server will be used not only to serve your Angular app, but also query your database and read/serve local files such as `index.html`. Regarding jQuery, it has no business with Angular. Remove it. _Now_.

Comment: yeah, jQuery is outside of my angualr2 application i wanted to save the time for starting a nodeJs server/Apachi/.. i thought i could use the ng server for it, thanks jeremy!